# Getting the "is not a static member of class" error in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a static int variable currentId for the class FBLPost so that every time a FBLPost object is created the new instance is assigned that id and the static currentId is incremented by 1 for the next new instance that is created. My constructor is implemented in FBLPost.cpp. This is a trivial task in java, but C++ is giving me a hard time. I have googled and have looked at other posts on SO so if I missed something forgive me. Here is my code and the errors:

```
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\myProjects\Assignment_3_220\Assignment3\FBLPost.h|31|error: 'int FBLPost::currentId' is not a static data member of 'class FBLPost'|
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\myProjects\Assignment_3_220\Assignment3\FBLPost.cpp||In constructor 'FBLPost::FBLPost()':|
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\myProjects\Assignment_3_220\Assignment3\FBLPost.cpp|5|error: 'currentId' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Of course currentId wasn't declared, I'm trying to declare it here.

Also if I try removing the static keyword I still get an error and if I try declaring the static variable inside FBLPost I get an error.

FBLPost.h

```
#ifndef FBLPOST_H_INCLUDED
#define FBLPOST_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
class FBLUser;

using namespace std;

class FBLPost {

   private:
    string Post = "";
    FBLPost* next = 0;
    int likes = 0;
    FBLUser* author;
    int id;

public:
    FBLPost();
    string getPost();
    void setPost(string p);
    FBLPost* getNext();
    void setNext(FBLPost* n);
    int getLikes();
    void incrementLikes();
    void setAuthor(FBLUser* user);
    FBLUser* getAuthor();
};

static int FBLPost::currentId = 0; //This line give me an error

#endif // FBLPOST_H_INCLUDED
```

FBLPost.cpp

```
#include "FBLPost.h"
using namespace std;

FBLPost::FBLPost() {
    id = ++currentId;
}


string FBLPost::getPost() {
    return Post;
}
void FBLPost::setPost(string p) {
   Post = p;
}
FBLPost* FBLPost::getNext() {
   return next;
}
void FBLPost::setNext(FBLPost* n) {
   next = n;
}

int FBLPost::getLikes() {
   return likes;
}
void FBLPost::incrementLikes() {
   likes++;
}

void FBLPost::setAuthor(FBLUser* user) {
   author = user;
}
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: You cannot add extra members after the class declaration. The id *really* isn't a member of the class.

Comment: You need to add `static int currentId;` in your class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring better ways to do this... you are getting the error because currentId is *not* being declared a member of FBLPost.

```
... snip ...
class FBLPost {

   private:
    string Post = "";
    FBLPost* next = 0;
    int likes = 0;
    FBLUser* author;
    int id;
    static int currentId;
... snip ...
```

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to initialize `currentId` in `FBLPost`'s declaration - you're already doing that with `static int FBLPost::currentId = 0;`.

Comment: I just tried that now I'm getting C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\myProjects\Assignment_3_220\Assignment3\FBLPost.h|18|error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'FBLPost::currentId'|